# Conditional Formatting in Ms-Access 2010, caveats using double as datatype

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I ran into a Problem while designing a form with conditional formatting in Ms-Access 2010. I am calculating a sum of all molecular ingredients of a specific material. Theoretically it should add up to 100, always. I want to use conditional formatting to give visual feedback to the user, if said sum does not equal to 100. I did set it up in a way that, whenever the value of the field does not equal to 100, the textfield's background becomes red. For most records this is working as intended, but on some it doesn't. I have build the sum for these records manually and assure they add up to 100, but the conditonal formatting still displays them with red ackground, but the value displayed is 100,00. It seems like the calculation is right, but the conditionals are wrong.

Someone suggested to use VBA, but adviced against it, too. I am not clear on this and do not know how I should solve this problem. I crosschecked the msdn forum and google on this matter, but everything I did seems to be in line with the specs. Could the community give me a hint?

If there is additional info, I'll glady provide them.

Comment: What data type do you use in fields? If it's double (floating point), may be your sum is not exactly 100. Try to use Round function

Comment: Indeed, all the values are doubles. double-facepalm-worthy of me. Using Round() I was able to get desired results. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are adding floating point numbers, and in some records rounding errors creep in and prevent the sum from being exactly 100.

Use the Round() function or something like `Abs([mySum] - 100) > 0.001` as criterium for making the background red.

Comment: This, exactly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Krysopath: If you feel an answer solves your problem: accept it (l^click on the v-mark on the left of the respective answer. This gives others the signal: this question is answered and it gives the one that helped you additional reputation points